# Aren't there road signs that show populations of towns in the UK?

Tags: uk, driving, london, swindon

I had a trip from Heathrow Airport to Swindon and later turned back to the airport via the M4. During the trip I haven't noticed any signs that show populations of towns.

[image]

When I searched for London on the internet, the results were mostly for a city in Canada.

[image]

Did I miss the road signs or aren't there any signs?

Comment: Is this common at all outside of the USA?

Comment: I have never seen such signs anywhere, and I have traveled a fair bit of Europe.

Comment: No you didn't miss the signs, they don't exist.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76351/discussion-on-question-by-ahmedus-arent-there-road-signs-that-show-populations).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I have lived in five countries including the UK and never seen such a sign in real life.  I only know them from American movies, where I've always semi-felt they were some sort of Wild West joke or something, like when they reduce the number by one after a lynching.  I can't conceive of why the population would be posted outside a town, rather than its GDP, area in hectares, name of its mayor, or some other random datum.

Comment: Sometimes a municipal boundary sign (e.g. "city limit," "town line," "urban boundary," "corporation limit," etc.) does name the mayor, or commonly [the elevation](https://www.flickr.com/photos/quartzcity/21953023). The population, historically, gave you a rough idea of what services you could find there (or whether it was worth a salesman's stop), although in the Interstate era there will be a separate, more useful sign specifically indicating whether fuel, food, lodging, etc. are available. Populations are not usually given at county or state lines.

Comment: Elevation is common, especially in mountainous areas.  I always wonder how they stick a precise number on an area that presumably actually comprises a range of elevations.

Comment: @choster: I'm impressed by the precision of the number on that sign. Now I'm imagining they must have an entire city department dedicated to repainting those numbers every morning incorporating yesterday's births, deaths, and moves ...

Comment: They're not just in movies! These signs are incredibly common in the US.

Comment: "I can't conceive of why the population would be posted outside a town, rather than its GDP, area in hectares, name of its mayor, or some other random datum." Town limit signs in the US do have a wide array of random data on them actually. Population or elevation are most common but I've seen a few displaying the accomplishments of a local person or sports team. One of the town limit signs in my own hometown proclaimed it to be the home of an astronaut for example.

Comment: @EldritchWarlord "Welcome to the town this person disliked so much they went to space to get away from it!"

Comment: My current town of residence now has a sign that reads "750 friendly people (and a couple of sore heads)". Yes, really. I'll chime in to agree that these types of signs are pretty common in the US, probably more so in rural areas, but even [large cities](https://www.flickr.com/photos/quartzcity/21953023) have them. The elevation listed is the "official" survey altitude at a specific point with no implication that the whole town is billiard table flat, nor is it an average.

Comment: @FreeMan, I rather like the [Anatone population sign](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Anatone,_WA_2010.jpg).

Comment: There are laws in the US which are dependent on whether you are in a city or what the population of the city/county is, so the posting of the population serves a legal function. A common one is hunting regulations, outside cities or in sparsely populated counties, hunting times/Sunday hunting may be extended. Riding horses/driving off road vehicles on the street is another example.

Comment: This is probably one of the worst highly voted answers I've ever seen. Not only does it not answer the question, it expresses an opinion about why the idea is stupid, when it is an actual documented fact! Even evidenced by a picture in the question!

Comment: @HenningMakholm The signs are typically updated after the census, which takes place every 10 years.

Comment: @Phill The question is "Do these signs exist in the UK?" and the answer is that Amy has lived in the UK and not seen them, which is reasonable evidence that they aren't common.

Comment: @FreeMan I would have expected the elevation at the location of the sign.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - not necessarily. The town I grew up in was officially 4477 feet. If I recall correctly, the marker for that was at a public park on the south end of town, but not at the city limit by any means (might have been city limits when the town was first incorporated, but I don't think so). It was also one of the lower points in a town that started in the valley and grew up the benches on both the east & west side of town.

Comment: @Phill firstly, its impossible to prove a negative - if one single town in the UK does post its population on highway signs, then you can't say "no" in response to "aren't there any signs?".  Any British resident, however, can certainly affirm that its so rare that its basically a negative - I'm a Brit who has lived all over the UK and can safely say I have never seen such a sign.  Add to that the fact that even though you say "when it is an actual documented fact" and correctly agree "Even evidenced by a picture in the question!" doesn't make the opinion that its stupid *wrong*.

Answer (score 38):

1. Most villages/towns/cities have signs saying "Welcome to *{name of village/town/city}*", but they (almost exclusively) don't have populations on them in the UK.
2. When you drive along motorways, like the M4, you don't go into any villages/towns/ cities, so you don't see the "Welcome to *{name of village/town/city}*" signs. You do see "Welcome to *{name of county}*" though.
3. London, UK, possibly doesn't have these signs anyway - London's too big. I expected to find signs to the boroughs and/or the towns and villages that have been absorbed into Greater London, but I didn't find anything for "Welcome to Westminster sign" on google images, or for Hackney or Brixton either. Possibly only smaller towns and villages bother with the signs. I did find [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=770&bih=742&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=WNTVWvi6NcvEgQaQ5pqIDA&q=welcome%20to%20kingston%20sign&oq=welcome%20to%20kingston%20sign&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0.152397.153803.0.153994.9.9.0.0.0.0.95.557.9.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.270...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13k1.0.wyzgu2VIl6I#imgrc=XMi1HdUD6SHU9M:) for Tolworth, an area of the Kingston-upon-Thames borough.

Comment: Also never seen population on such a sign, neither in the UK nor France where signs are more standardised.  I think you can make a stronger statement.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that you do get "Welcome to <county>" signs on motorways.

Comment: Has always amused me that on the M40 you get "Welcome to Buckinghamshire", then "Welcome to Oxfordshire" and then "Welcome to Buckinghamshire" again. Can be easy to think "What?!? Have I gone around in a circle!?".

Comment: Can confirm that London boroughs often (but not always) have a welcome sign, typically featuring the borough's logo or coat of arms. The City of London (not to be confused with the rest of London) has [these guys](https://goo.gl/maps/H36nygXVKM82).

Comment: In the UK you do have hundreds of settlement signs that say "Welcome to X Please drive carefully" and someone has scratched out two of the letters in the word 'drive' so it looks like ["Please die carefully"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Please+die+carefully&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

Comment: @WhatEvil heh... Try driving in Northern Ireland...

Comment: @Ambo100 Also, hundreds of settlement signs that say "Welcome to X Please drive slowly." OK, I'll close my eyes and do 10mph because that's all that they require.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We also have instructions for [rabbits](https://goo.gl/maps/ewSJ11PFMUs) and [semi-aquatic apes](https://goo.gl/maps/jSqKBaEAuiA2).  In England, it's easy to amuse yourself on boring car journeys by looking at the map and finding bizarre names of villages.

Comment: @Ambo100 That reminds me of the signs outside Bothell, WA that used to read "Welcome to ---hell, for a day, or for a lifetime"

Comment: I quite often drive past signs "Welcome to Lambeth" as I'm entering Lambeth from Croydon - I'm just struggling to find specific locations on google map a the moment.

Comment: Here's [one for Lewisham](http://www.asp-removals.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/House-removals-Lewisham.jpg) which is in Forest Hill.

Comment: The City of Westminster does indeed have a “Welcome to Westminster” on major routes into the borough. There is one not far from my house, I will try to snap a picture if you are interested.

Comment: Random trivia.  The City of London has the smallest population of any English city (at least in 2011 census).  Implausible until you remember that the City itself is only one of 33 districts in the metropolis of London and it's mainly businesses.

Comment: @Alchymist - Yes, there's a big difference between The City of London and the city of London.

Answer (score 30):

At least one existed: one was erected in Trowbridge in 1999, and then replaced later. But they are exceedingly rare, and I'm not entirely sure that these count as 'road signs'.

[image: Sign: "Trowbridge -- Welcome to the County Town of Wiltshire -- 45m above sea level -- Population 27,500 (and more information)]

[image: Sign: "Trowbridge -- Welcome to the County Town of Wiltshire -- 45m above sea level -- Population 35,000 (and more information)]

[Source: Geograph](http://www.geograph.org.uk/photos/383389)

Comment: This is something a little different, however. These kinds of signs are promotional, and may be erected by the town itself or by a civic organization; the one depicted in the OP is a standardized road sign whose installation and upkeep may be mandated by statute.

Comment: Good work. I assumed there was a chance of there being one *somewhere* in the UK.

Comment: Yep, very well done for finding this. Interesting to note that Trowbridge clearly had a major population surge between the time when those two signs were installed.  :-D

Comment: @Simba coming from just down the road, why that would possibly be the case is a total mystery to me.

Comment: @Simba It was probably the creation of a new sign making company, and the acquisition of several sign-making-engineers, along with their massive extended families and all their friends.

Comment: Census data suggests a steady increase of 2-4,000 per decade since WWII, rather than a surge at any point. https://history.wiltshire.gov.uk/community/getcensus.php?item=Trowbridge

Answer (score 10):

According to a brief google search (and from personally visiting several countries on different continents), the population number on the welcome sign seems to be a North American custom. I've never seen this anywhere else.

So, to answer your question, there most likely are no such signs, you didn't miss them.

Comment: According to the OP, "All cities and towns in Turkey have such signs, that's why I expected to see them in the UK too."

Answer (score 5):

You didn't miss them - they don't exist here, or indeed almost anywhere outside of the USA as far as I've seen.

Also, our councils can hardly manage to fill potholes, posting optional factoids on signs is just extravagance.

Comment: According to the OP, "All cities and towns in Turkey have such signs, that's why I expected to see them in the UK too."

Comment: I've only visited ~30 of the ~50 countries of Europe, hence "as far as I've seen" rather than "by exhaustive international survey".

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, town signs in the UK don't have the population on. What they do quite often have, however, is "twinned with", showing the other towns and cities they are partnered with for cultural exchange reasons - as shown on the bottom of the Trowbridge sign in @Dragon's post

Comment: "Welcome to Norfolk, twinned with itself"

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, we have no local registration of one's residence.  You can move somewhere and the only thing the council knows about a change in residence, is one name on the council tax bill, a new kid in a school, new benefit claim, etc.  There is no need to register other family members or lodgers.

The only reasonably reliable count of population is every 10 years when the census is taken. The rest of the time, it would be a costly hassle for councils to maintain such a sign.

Answer (score -8):

I would say, as the UK is a highly compact country with everything close together. It would be impossible for those signs to exist because the constant changes within population when moving between two towns can take under an hour.

Also, this is kinda an American custom. Which English people would never want to adopt (we feel useless enough, you don't have to remind us how many people we have to compete with) .

Comment: You're aware that people are born, die and move house in the US, too?

Comment: We feel useless? Speak for yourself. For such a small island/population we have such a huge global presence, and should be proud of what we have accomplished (but perhaps not always the paths we took to accomplish it..).

Comment: The populations listed in these signs are in no way required to be updated frequently. In the US most are updated at most every 10 years (after the Census).

Comment: @DavidRicherby though not usually in that order ;-)

Comment: @JamesTrotter: And you have an impressive number of great rock bands.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It appears that the American tolerance for displaying data that becomes outdated in a few days but can't be updated for years is higher than it is in other countries.

Comment: @JamesTrotter - +1 for the comments you made within the brackets :) Thank you :)